# Add div inside li using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list `<li id="somelist"> </li>`

I want to put a div inside it like this `<div>SomeDiv</div>`

The final output should be `<li id="somelist"><div>SomeDiv</div></li>`

How do I do this using jquery?

Comment: $('#someList').html('<div>SomeDiv</div>');
This is basic jquery you could learn from their site.

Answer (score 3):

You can [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) `<div>SomeDiv</div>` to the li element:

```
$('li#somelist').append('<div>SomeDiv</div>');
```

Comment: I thought append would grow the list. Would it insert inside the li element?

Comment: Yap, it will :) do what you want, inside the `<li>`

Comment: @BhagyashreeJog You're confusing `append` with `after`.